# How can I escape special character '#' in thymeleaf th:attr

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, template-engine, thymeleaf

I am using special character '#' as follows:

```
th:attr="data-target=#my_modal_+${myObject.id}"
```

This fails with error because of special character '#'

> Could not parse as assignation sequence

If i remove '#' it doesnt throw error but doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found solution, needed quotes around #my_modal_

```
th:attr="data-target='#my_modal_'+${myObject.id}"
```

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML change id="my_modal" to class="my_modal"

Then you could do something like

```
th:attr="data-target=.my_modal_+${myObject.class}"
```

By using a class which in CSS uses a "." instead of a "#" this should hopefully resolve the issue.